# Does my daughter need permission to travel without me?

Tags: uk

I have  been  living for  4  years  in  London with  my  daughter and  my  mother. My daughter has two nationalities - Bulgarian and Greek. I am  separated, not divorced from her father. He lives in Bulgaria. Can my  daughter travel without me (with another person such as my  mother)? She would have written permission (authorisation  paper) given only by  me.

Comment: Travel where? For international travel, there are often regulations concerning minors travelling without a parent or a legal guardian, but even within the EU, there are relevant differences from country to country.

Comment: How old is your daughter ?

Answer (score 3):

It will depend on her age, and where she is travelling.  I assume that she is still a child, but if she has reached the age of majority for the UK and for the country where she is traveling, then she will be treated as an adult and can travel freely.

Typically, a child needs the written permission of both parents to travel abroad (or from one parent, if the other is present), and usually this permission should be notarized to give greater assurance of its accuracy.  I also recommend that you provide contact information for the parent(s) in question so that the customs and immigration officer at the destination country can verify the permission if needed.

Do not be surprised if an immigration officer wishes to interview the child alone for a few minutes; this is sometimes done to check with the child to ensure that the child is not being removed against a parent's will.

User Giorgio also commented (very appropriately) that the UK has special standards for minors entering the country: ["Home Address" in the UK](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100512/home-address-in-the-uk/100523#100523).  His post at that link is well worth reading.

Comment: You might want to add the higher standard enforced by the UK under the [Child Protection Act](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100512/home-address-in-the-uk/100523#100523) as the minor exits and re-enters the country.

Comment: @Giorgio your post was very well written, so I've added a reference to it and a link to it directly.

Comment: I'm not too sure. The child has freedom of movement in the UK as a Greek citizen. They can't refuse the child entry.

Comment: @greatone The child may have a right to enter, but will require evidence that her parents have consented to her traveling abroad without them.  If her parents have legal custody of her in a foreign country, I don't believe her right to enter takes precedence over her rights to enter a different country as a citizen.

Comment: @Jim MacKenzie read the answer below.

Comment: @greatone That post comments on returning to the UK, but not at all about entering another country, which is how I interpreted the question.

Comment: @Jim MacKenzie  The UK will not stop the child from leaving. That's what he's asking for.

Comment: "Can my daughter travel without me?" That implies both leaving and arriving :) I'll wait for the original poster to clarify the question.