# Leaving the UK without an accompanied child

Tags: uk

I will be visiting the UK on a visitor visa with my family, my wife and two children, aged 16 and 8 years. I will be staying in London with my sister's family, who is a British citizen. She will provide a proof of accommodation for us in theUK.

I am planning to visit France for three days with my wife from London, leaving my children with my sister. However, I will come back and exit the UK finally with my children.

If I exit the UK for France, will I be stopped at the airport because I entered the UK with accompanied children and I would be leaving without them?

What are the different options available?

1. Should my sister declare that she will take care of my children in my absence? In this case what additional documents may she need to provide? She too has two children.
2. Should I drop the idea of visiting France completely?

Is there any other option?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While your question is not a duplicate, you may wish to take a look at [this question regarding bringing minor children into the UK](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100512/home-address-in-the-uk/100523#100523)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information. It appears to be a tricky situation for me. It will be better if I drop the plan for visiting France and stick to UK only.

Comment: So finally I decided to not take children with us.

Answer (score 3):

It is not usual to be checked on exit from the UK, although it can happen.
France will likely not be concerned about you traveling with or without your children.

But on your return to the UK you can be denied entry for many reasons and then you will have a lot of trouble to get your children with you again.